# How to start single PHP session?

Tags: php, session

I'm looking for a way to start a single PHP session, but nothing seems to work.

I've tried doing like this:

`session_start($_SESSION['check_rank']);`

But it didn't work.. I got the following error:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: _SESSION in /Applications/MAMP/MyProjects/teste/teste.php on line 4
PHP Warning:  session_start() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /Applications/MAMP/MyProjects/teste/teste.php on line 4
```

Is there a way to start only a single section?

Comment: You cannot start a single session.. when you use session_start() you start the session between the client and server. and only then, do you assign session variables a value..

session_start(); $_SESSION['variable'] = "value";

Comment: '$_SESSION' is like an array, if you want to store data then add it to only one key. and to start session you have to use `session_start()`.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain what exactly you mean by "start a single PHP session". Do you mean starting a session with a particular name? In that case have a look at [`session_name()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php).

Comment: Options only came into effect as of 7.0 http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php I quote: *"7.0.0  The options parameter was added."* - So what's your version of PHP? I hope you're not going to make us all stare at your question/comments to get anything out of you.

Comment: I mean start a different section, I have my main section with the `user_id` and  `user_name` on it, now I want a different one, with only the `user_level` on this one, when I run `session_start` should be loaded only the values of this section, not the main one.

Comment: you didn't answer my question: what version of PHP are you using? I'll bet you're confused with `session_register()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php that does accept an argument `session_register("barney");` - am I right?

Comment: I'm getting tired of staring at comments here. You will need to ping me or someone else directly by using the @ symbol followed by my/their name. I have to leave the question now, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

What is a "single" PHP session? Never heard of it.

session_start() takesno parameter, it just starts the session. If you want to call/start a named session, you have to use session_name().

e.g.

```
<?php
session_name("my-session");
session_start();
```

$_SESSION is to store session variables,

e.g.

```
<?php
session_name("my-session");
session_start();

$_SESSION["foo"] = "bar";
```

Comment: `session_start()` does not take a name parameter. You are confusing it with `session_name()` (which does not start a session). Although from PHP 7 onwards it appears you *can* pass it an array with a `name` key. I haven't tested this, though.

Comment: Options only came into effect as of 7.0 http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php I quote: *"7.0.0  The options parameter was added."*